# How to numpy-slicing an image without getting "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Tags: python, opencv, crop

I'm getting the error :

> "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

when i try to crop an image

I'm trying to write a function that crop an rectangular image in order to make a squared image and centered.

```
def squared_and_resized(img,resized_dim):
    image = cv2.imread(img)
    img_height,img_width = image.shape[:2]
    if (img_width > img_height):
            start_row = 0
            end_row = img_height
            start_col = math.floor((img_width - img_height) /2)
            end_col = math.floor((img_width + img_height) /2)
    else:
            start_col = 0
            end_col = img_width
            start_row = math.floor((img_height-img_width)/2)
            end_row = start_row + img_width

    squared_img = img[start_row:end_row , start_col:end_col]

    resized_img = cv2.resize(squared_img,(resized_dim, resized_dim))
    return resized_img
```

Comment: provide complete error message. At first look it looks like you are trying to slice a string instead of image. Recheck your variable name and make sure you haven't use same variable name twice.

Comment: In your code: `image = cv2.imread(img)`.

Answer (score 0):

math.floor returns a float type variable. You could use `int(math.floor((img_height-img_width)/2))`

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the line: `squared_img = img[start_row:end_row , start_col:end_col]`. Upon code inspection it seems that `img` is of type `str` which is being passed to this method and later used for image slicing. You may need to use `squared_img = image[start_row:end_row , start_col:end_col]`

To mitigate this issue in future, please use meaningful names. In this case the method param could be named as `image_path`.